# How to connect Angular 2 with MySql Database using Nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, rest, angular2-services

I started new project for Retail Shop, I need to connect Angular 2/5 with MySQL Database using Node or any other method. I need Examples for Select, Create, Delete, Update. for now i need to create Login Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can do that is through http requests to the nodeJs server, since Angular runs in the web browser, while node runs on a server (javascript execution environment).
To create an Http service in Angular you can follow this [link](https://angular.io/guide/http). In this way the nodejs server will be able to receive the data and be able to process them through a connection to mysql.

Comment: This is standard from the books comment with not additional information. Further more ok http service but from the question it seems that he needs better understanding of how a front end application gets and puts its data to a server. SO call a REST API using the http service is correct though. This is really beginner stuff tbh...

Answer (score 0):

Well connecting Angular???

First learn that Angular, front end, does never connect to any database directly (not counting a New England db or LocalStorage as Database).

You need node or any other server side technology and then serve a REST API for providing data to your front end applications. SO actually your front end app in Angular is a complete separate application and your server side application will only connect to DB, handle logic and serve a REST API.

I use [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html) for easy connecting and writing queries in JSON syntax.

Some more resources:

https://www.sitepoint.com/user-authentication-mean-stack/
https://medium.com/of-all-things-tech-progress/starting-with-authentication-a-tutorial-with-node-js-and-mongodb-25d524ca0359

Full Example app: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/02/22/mean-with-angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Angular is for your front end. 
If you want Angular like syntax / Typescript for the back-end / server, have a look at: [nest](https://docs.nestjs.com/).
Nest (NestJS) is a framework for building scalable Node.js server-side applications.